# Is there anyway to know from what console is an user logged?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, shell

Is there anyway to know from what console is an user logged ?

with the who command gives me:

```
NAME     LINE         TIME             COMMENT
atomsfat  pts/0        2011-08-02 08:52 (172.206.24.244)
atomsfat  pts/2        2011-08-02 09:01 (172.206.24.244)
atomsfat  pts/4        2011-08-02 09:01 (172.206.24.244)
atomsfat  pts/5        2011-08-02 11:48 (172.206.24.244)
```

And with whoami command just say:
    atomsfat

How can I get the current console in use in my session ? 
 for example: pts/5

Comment: Are you trying to take control over a console already in use? What distribution? more info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `tty(1)`.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/6
```